# Gradle sync fails to find add-on after updating to version 2.0.0-rc2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I want to try out Instant Run on Android Studio 2.0 with the project I am working on. I have been trying to set it up unsuccessfully for hours now.

I am using Android Studio 2.0 RC2. I have it as a separate installation from the other stable version. When I started the project with the new Android Studio it updated the gradle files so I will be able to use Instant Run. There were a small number of changes, one of which was updating `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.1` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-rc2`. Updating the Gradle version caused there to be an error on Gradle Sync:

> Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'Hewlett-Packard
>   Development Company, L.P.:HP Android Print SDK Add-On:23' in:
>   D:\Android\sdk

This error is caused by this line: `compileSdkVersion "Hewlett-Packard Development Company, L.P.:HP Android Print SDK Add-On:23"`, in my gradle file (it was not modified by the update). I am sure that I have the add-on that I am trying to include in *sdk\add-ons* where it is required to be. The problem is in this line, with this add-on. Other add-ons are included in the same way in the gradle file but there is no problem with them. Note that there were no problems with the same code before updating the gradle files.

Any idea how to deal with this add-on problem?

Comment: what about `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'` or `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2'`

Comment: When I try it I get this:
Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "48825004e7e3cb0ca0c710cb3b06381527ef215a"

Comment: I tried adding the variable and then restarting the studio but nothing changed.

Comment: then `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta7`

Comment: It accepts the beta7 version but I get the same add-on problem.

Comment: did you find a solution to that? It´s happening to me with Samsung sdk add-on.

Comment: Yes, I have the solution. Some of the parameters in the source.properties file of the add-on needed to be edited. I will be posting an answer on Monday (I don't have the changes in my current location).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! Changes had to be made to the *source.properties* file. It is important that the `Addon.NameDisplay` matches the add-on name that you use in the string in the Gradle file (the contents of the `name` property in *manifest.ini*) and `Addon.VendorDisplay` to match the vendor in the same string (the contents of the `vendor` property in *manifest.ini*). You should also move the `libraries` property from *manifest.ini* to *source.properties*.

I still get a Gradle error about the plugin but the projects compiles and runs with Instant Run without problems.

This is the contents of the old file that I had problems with:

```
Addon.NameId=HP
Pkg.Desc=HP Lib
Addon.VendorId=hp
Pkg.License=hp
Archive.Arch=ANY
Pkg.LicenseRef=android-sdk-license
Addon.NameDisplay=HP Android Print SDK Add-On
Addon.VendorDisplay=Hewlett-Packard Development Company, L.P.
Archive.Os=ANY
Pkg.SourceUrl=https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Pkg.Revision=3
AndroidVersion.ApiLevel=23
```

This is how the updated file looks like:

```
Addon.NameId=HP Android Print SDK Add-On
Pkg.Desc=HP Print SDK Add-On
Addon.VendorId=hp
Pkg.Revision=21
AndroidVersion.ApiLevel=23
libraries=com.hp.pps.print.sdk;com.amazon.device.print
com.hp.pps.print.sdk=hpprintsdk.jar;HP Print SDK Library
com.amazon.device.print=amazonprintsdk.jar;Amazon Print SDK Library
Addon.NameDisplay=HP Android Print SDK Add-On
Addon.VendorDisplay=Hewlett-Packard Development Company, L.P.
```

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it looks like the compileSdkVersion should simply be the numerical value, 23.
If you can provide some more information, it would help the HP Print SDK team troubleshoot the problem.
You can get support directly by signing up at http://www.mobileprintsdk.com/mobile-print-sdk/android_features. It's free, and the team is very responsive. We'll even post the answer here, once we figure out the issue. :-)